# Agda: How to apply +-right-identity to match types

Tags: agda

Somewhere in my code, I have a hole which expects a natural number, let's call it `n` for our purposes. I have a function which returns me a `n + 0`.

`Data.Nat.Properties.Simple` contains a proof `+-right-identity` of the following type:

`+-right-identity : ∀ n → n + 0 ≡ n`

I'm not familiar enough with the Agda syntax and stdlib yet to know how to easily use this proof to convince the type checker that I can use my value.

More generally, how to I use a relation `x ≡ y` to transform a given `x` into `y`?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in this thread: [Agda Type-Checking and Commutativity / Associativity of +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949323/agda-type-checking-and-commutativity-associativity-of)

For future readers, the keyword I was looking for was `rewrite`.

By appending `rewrite +-right-identity n` to the pattern matching (before the `=` sign), Agda "learned" about this equality.